# How do I dynamically update nested lists with d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have JSON with tree structure. I render it like this:

```
var lis = d3.select("#active ul")
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(getTopLevelChildren(), nodeId);
lis.enter().append("li").each(makeNodeView);
```

`makeNodeView` does this same thing recursively, which creates a `ul`/`li` tree in the DOM.

However, I also want to dynamically update the list. This straight-forward code doesn't work:

```
lis.each(updateNodeView);
lis.exit().remove();
```

The problem is that `selectAll("li")` selected all the `li` nodes *recursively*. So `lis.exit().remove()` removes all `li` tags anywhere on the page except for those at the root of the tree.

How do I select only 1 level of the tree at a time?

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to add a class to all `li` elements that designates their level (e.g. `level1` etc) and select based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ul = d3.select(this).append("ul");
var lis = ul.selectAll(function () { return ul[0][0].childNodes })
```